# How to see the changes of a local DB against Server DB, if they are in sync? And how to sync them from time to time? no 3rd party tools

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, local-database

A continuation to [Sync large local DB with server DB (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931575/sync-large-local-db-with-server-db-mysql), how can we see the differences between a local DB and server DB, before we go for syncing them?

I dont want to use any third party tools.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Schema and Data comparison/synchronization tools in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). There are also separate tools for [data](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/schemacompare/) and [schema](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/) comparison.

Comment: I dont want to use 3rd party tools.

Comment: On the one server you can write a query to find changes (data and even schema). But when two servers have to be compared, the third party tool may be very helpful.